# Addressing Form objects with dynamic name

Tags: javascript, dynamic, textbox, cognos

I am using Cognos web reporting and we commonly use Javascript to manupulate the tool generated objects.
In this case, I have some textboxes on the page which are generated by Cognos and I can access them in javascript as: **fW._textEditBoxAsia.value**

Here, **fW** is the form name and **_textEditBoxAsia** is the tool generated field name for textbox.
I want to actually loop through all the textboxes and I know their names will be _textEditBoxAmerica, _textEditBoxEurope, _textEditBoxAustralia, and so on. I have the list of regions in an array. I just want some dynamic way to address the textboxes.

So, something like this:

```
for (var i=0; i< array.length; i++)   
{   (fW._textEditBox + array[i].value).value = 0 ;   }
```

Can you please guide me on how to achieve the above?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=0; i< array.length; i++)
{ 
    document.fW["_textEditBox" + array[i]].value = 0; 
}
```